# Using ALAsset Library select video from Library and convert that video to Datatype

Tags: ios4

I am using `ALAssert` library to select video from iPhone library and i am setting property of that video file like.

```
 (void)selectedAssets:(NSArray*)_assets {

NSMutableArray *returnArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

for(ALAsset *asset in _assets) {


    NSMutableDictionary *workingDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [workingDictionary setObject:[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaType"];

    [workingDictionary setObject:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[asset defaultRepresentation] fullScreenImage]] forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    [workingDictionary setObject:[[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] valueForKey:[[[asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs] allKeys] objectAtIndex:0]] forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL"];

    [workingDictionary setObject:[[asset defaultRepresentation]url] forKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL"];

    [returnArray addObject:workingDictionary];        
    [workingDictionary release];    
}

[self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

if([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(elcImagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)]) {
    [delegate performSelector:@selector(elcImagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) withObject:self withObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:returnArray]];
}
```

}

here i am setting `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` but i think its not a right to set `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` as i did all .

how do i give `UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL` property for selected video. and convert that video `MediaURL` to data type.

Comment: use UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL instead of UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL